# *ngIf not rendering in child component using @Import property

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-ng-if

I have `shared-components` module. It is exported by the `app.module` then imported in the module I want to use it. In `shared-components` module I have a component that is supposed to render base on 3 `*ngIf` elements (depending on number <, > or = to 0).
This component receives a number through @Import someNumber (initiated to undefined)

The component tag is included inside and `*ngFor` loop.

Inspecting HTML code, I can see that the component receives correct value for someNumber.
And interpolated evalutions `{{someNumber && (someNumber < 0)}` is correctly evaluated.
But no `*ngIf` get renderered.

*(I will progressively upgrade this question with (anonymised) code that seems relevant.)*

**child.component.html**

```html
{{(someNumber !== undefined) && (someNumber > 0)}} <!-- Renders true or false as expected -->
{{(someNumber !== undefined) && (someNumber === 0)}}  <!-- Renders true or false as expected -->
{{(someNumber !== undefined) && (someNumber < 0)}}  <!-- Renders true or false as expected -->
    
<ng-container *ngIf="(someNumber !== undefined) && (someNumber > 0)">...</ng-container> <!-- Never renders! -->
<ng-container *ngIf="(someNumber !== undefined) && (someNumber === 0)">...</ng-container> <!-- Never renders! -->
<ng-container *ngIf="(someNumber !== undefined) && (someNumber < 0)">...</ng-container> <!-- Never renders! -->
```

**child.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() someNumber : number | undefined;
    
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```html
<div id="stuff" class="container">
    <div *ngIf="y.length === 0" class="loading">Data is <b>loading</b>...</div>
    
    <div *ngFor="let x of y;" class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ x.b  | uppercase }}</h5>
            <div class="row">
                <ng-container *ngIf="x.a">
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <ul>
                            (...)
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="childComponent Container col-1">
                        <child-component [someNumber]="x.a.someNumber"></child-component>
                    </div>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container *ngIf="!x.a">
                    (...)
                </ng-container>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <a routerLink="/" class="btn btn-primary w-25">&lt; Back</a>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Which component are trying to display on condition?

Comment: It's a custom component (named here "child-component"), but the conditions (ngIf) that don't work are inside/part of the component.

Comment: does the `child-component` render outside the conditional with a static value? Something like `<child-component [someNumber]="5"></child-component>`?

Comment: Did you either import `CommonModule` in the module that owns child-component? Or import and export it in SharedModule?

Comment: @Jason White : Using a more simple tag as you suggested and placing it outside of the ngFor, the component behaves the same way (the interpolations render as text but the ngIfs do not render.

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 : import and export in shared module.
But I guess that if there was an issue with this, the interpolations {{}} wouldn't render at all.

Comment: I think (/am pretty sure) interpolation doesn't need CommonModule. But if CommonModule isn't added no mather what you pass to `*ngFor` it will not render ever, exactly like you describe.

Comment: @TTT What i meant was does the `child-compoent` render outside the *ngIf?  Does the `child-component` render as expected?

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 : I see, you are right, I restored the importation of CommonModule in the ShareComponentsModule and now the ngIfs render. (My mistake, this is all still quite new for me...)

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7: I'll let you write an answer so I can select it as solution. And thanks you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### CommonModule

If you don't add `CommonModule` to the module owning the component:

Interpolation will work:

```html
{{3 + 3}}   <!-- 6 -->
```

But anything containing `*ngFor` will never render.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="true">U will not see me</ng-container>  <!-- Never renders! -->
<ng-container *ngFor="false">U will not see me</ng-container>  <!-- Never renders! -->
<ng-container *ngFor="...">U will not see me</ng-container>  <!-- Never renders! -->
```

Comment: So that was indeed the issue, I had removed the importation of CommonModule from my SharedComponentsModule, not realising it was required. Thank you!